# Is there a limit at the voltage you can apply to a transformer primary?

Tags: transformer, basic

I have a 9v transformer but all it says is that, there is not info on the primary. The voltage supplied to my house is 120v. So, the transformer will just lower the voltage by a 0.075 factor, independently of the voltage I supply to the primary? is there a voltage limit to the voltage I can supply to the primary? what would happen if I were to used it in Europe for example, where they have double the voltage at home?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Overvoltage on a transformer can cause the core to saturate. Once the core saturates the effective inductance drops through the floor resulting in much higher than expected currents.

If you are lucky a protective device will trip/blow, if you are unlucky the transformer may go up in smoke.